# JAVA: How to pass on arguments of a map to be the value associated to the ID of another parent map

Tags: java, maps

I'm not too clear on the terminology, so excuse the title.

What I'm looking for is the answer on how to do this:
This is the map:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> theMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();
```

And this is the way I'm trying to add to it, I hope it provides enough insight:

```
theMap.put("string", {"a"="b"});
```

(that doesn't work)

Comment: Is `{"a"="b"}` the only entry of `string`?

Comment: The "{"a"="b"}" is supposed to be the entire argument for the creation of that map inside of the parent map! I'm sorry, I don't know how to better explain it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a `Map<String, String>` to a `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` the code below is the way to go:

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> theMap = new HashMap<String, Map<String, String>>();

Map<String, String> innerMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
innerMap.put("a", "b");

theMap.put("string", innerMap);
```

We create a variable `innerMap` of type `Map<String, String>` and simply add it to the `theMap` object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add subMap to theMap object :

```
Map<String, Map<String, String>> theMap = new HashMap<>();

    Map<String, String> subMap = new HashMap<>();
    subMap.put("a","b");

    theMap.put("string",subMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

The value is `Map<String, String>`, not `String`. You need to add new `Map` and insert the values to this `Map`

```
theMap.put("string", new LinkedHashMap<String, String>() {{
    put("a","b");
}});
```